# Unable to create registry value using C# giving error Unhandeled error 'System.Security.SecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#

I use the following code for creating a registry key Nodrives with its value 3FFFFFF at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`

but its giving me security exception.

```
RegistryKey rkey;
rkey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies", true); 
rkey.CreateSubKey("Explorer"); 
rkey.SetValue("NoDrives", "3FFFFFF");
rkey.Close();
```

Is the code correct or need any modifications??

Comment: You have verified you have permissions to write to that key...yes?

Comment: I think you don't have permission to write the key. Try to run your app as administrator, if you want to do this programmatically check this http://developz.blogspot.it/2013/02/uac-run-as-administrator-your-c.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably the "Explorer" already exists, and then `CreateSubKey` fails.

You should try to open ...\Explorer, and only if it doesn't exist create it.

Answer (score 0):

try force your app run as administrator. You can follow below steps:

In the Solution Explorer => Right click project name => add new item => choose "Application Manifest File" => click add => open manifest file => change "requestedExecutionLevel" node to: